# md5deep ubuntu install - command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to use md5deep on ubunutu. I have run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install md5deep
```

This successfully installs. However, I then run:

```
md5deep
```

And get the error message:

```
 md5deep:command not found
```

I have read the first 10-20 google pages on installing this and watched a number of youtube videos but unable to get part this first step.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here? (not sure if this is a linux question rather than a md5deep question)

My output for:

```
dpkg -L md5deep
```

is:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/md5deep
/usr/share/doc/md5deep/copyright
/usr/share/doc/md5deep/changelog.Debian.gz
```

My output for:

```
dpkg -L hashdeep
```

is:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/README.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/FILEFORMAT
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/TODO.gz
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/copyright
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/hashdeep/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/hashdeep.1.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/hashdeep
```

Running off: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: SSS, what is your ubuntu version? What was output of `sudo apt-get install md5deep` and what is output of `dpkg -L md5deep` and `dpkg -L hashdeep` commands? Try also to reopen Terminal.

Comment: Thanks - I updated question to answer this - and yes I tried new terminal

Comment: Check file /usr/bin/hashdeep with: `ls -l /usr/bin/hashdeep`, `/usr/bin/hashdeep --help`, `ldd /usr/bin/hashdeep`. Just use hashdeep command with option of... `-c md5` (http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/hashdeep.html), absence of `md5deep` alias is like a error in 16.04 & 16.10; fixed in 17.04

Comment: Thansks - that works and makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: This is bug of hashdeep package (since debian); Use `hashdeep -c md5` in older ubuntu; fixed in 17.04 (upgrade your ubuntu or try to downgrade package or use backports; or try to recompile into deb newer package or do `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/hashdeep /usr/bin/md5deep` or `sudo ln -s hashdeep /usr/bin/md5deep` as hack).

In debian and Ubuntu (some version before 16.04 or in it, actually 15.10) `md5deep` package was replaced by `hashdeep` package. Now, in 17.04 "zesty" `md5deep` is not a real package but just a "link" (transitional dummy package) to `hashdeep` package:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/md5deep

> transitional dummy package for hashdeep

Most recent version of hashdeep (from 17.04 "zesty")  http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/hashdeep can be installed by `sudo apt-get install hashdeep` and has all needed commands:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/hashdeep/filelist  (only /usr/bin part)

```
/usr/bin/hashdeep
/usr/bin/md5deep
/usr/bin/sha1deep
/usr/bin/sha256deep
/usr/bin/tigerdeep
/usr/bin/whirlpooldeep
```

But the problem (bug) is that 16.04 and 16.10 versions of hashdeep lacked 5 additional names in /usr/bin including `md5deep`:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/hashdeep/filelist
http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/hashdeep/filelist

```
 /usr/bin/hashdeep
```

This is marked in Changelog of the recent package: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/h/hashdeep/hashdeep_4.4-4/changelog

> hashdeep (4.4-3) ...  22 Sep 2016 
>        debian/hashdeep.links:
>         - Added to enable multi-call for md5deep and others.
>           (Closes: #795053, LP: #1525217, #1577293)

Bugs listed are:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=795053 "hashdeep: Important functions disabled by symlink removal" - 10 Aug 2015 - Found in version hashdeep/4.4-1; Fixed in version hashdeep/4.4-3
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/md5deep/+bug/1525217 "md5deep binary is missing" - Ubuntu 15.10 - 2015-12-11 --  2017-03-29
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hashdeep/+bug/1577293 "binary not available in package" - 16.04 -  2016-05-02 -- 2016-11-03

  > The program has different options and features when run with the names "hashdeep" and "md5deep"